# $\|h\mu\|= \int |h|d|\mu|$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, radon-nikodym

I was reading Conway and [image] just popped in. I am trying to prove the note that part, but I cannot. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How do you define $\|\nu\|$ for a measure $\nu,$ it usually _is defined_ as $|\nu|(\mathrm{X}).$ So, the result follows instantly by definition.

Comment: Do you mean $\|h\mu\|= |h\mu|(X)=\int |h|d|\mu|$?

Comment: By definition, $\| h \mu\| := |h \mu|(\mathrm{X}) = \int_\mathrm{X} |h| d|\mu|,$ the las equality follows because $|h \mu| = |h| |\mu|.$

Answer (score 3):

There exists a measurable function $\phi$ such that $|\phi|=1$ a.e. [$|\mu|$] and $d\mu =\phi d|\mu|$. Let $\nu(E)=\int_E h\phi d|\mu|$ so $\nu(E)=\int_E h d\mu$. It is clear from definition that $|\nu| \leq \int |h\phi | d|\mu|=\int |h | d|\mu|$. Now show that $\int_E|h|d|\mu|=\int_E \overline {\phi}  g d\nu$ where $g=\frac h {|h|}$ when $h \neq 0$ and $1$ when $h=0$. [ Use simple function approximation]. This gives $\int |h|d|\mu| \leq |\nu|$.